# How to join lists of ordered strings in Python?

Tags: python, list, unordered-set

I have a list of lists of strings that are ordered. I need to merge them into one list keeping the overall order intact. In other words, each list defines a relative ordering between elements, and we want to return the global ordering for all elements

For example:

Input:

```
[
    ["Pikachu", "Charmander", "Bulbasaur"],
    ["Charmander", "Ditto"],
    ["Bulbasaur", "Arcanine", "Venusaur"],
    ["Ditto", "Bulbasaur", "Venusaur"],
]
```

Output:

```
["Pikachu", "Charmander", "Ditto", "Bulbasaur", "Arcanine", "Venusaur"]
```

There can be multiple solutions. I am stuck on how to proceed.

Comment: Why is `"Ditto"` before `"Bulbasaur"` in your example output? I can't figure out a definition of "ordered" that works with this output.

Comment: @rchome: Because Ditto and Bulbasaur are ordered that way in the fourth sublist of the input.

Comment: Ah so to be clear, each list defines a relative ordering between elements, and we want to return the global ordering for all elements

Comment: I believe you may make use of NetworkX and construct the dependency graph, and iterate the resulting graph in some way

Comment: This is a job for a [topological sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting) - the list of lists induces a directed graph with elements as nodes, and a topological sort of this graph produces a valid combined ordering.

Comment: Okay, so it is more complex than I first assumed it to be. I will read up on topological sort, thank you!

Comment: (NetworkX has a topological sort built in. I would still recommend reading up on the concepts, but you don't have to write the algorithm yourself.)

Answer (score 1):

As @user2357112 mentioned in the comments, it is a job for a topological sort. I found this question is quite similar to the LeetCode problem [[444. Sequence Reconstruction]](https://leetcode.com/problems/sequence-reconstruction/), while the leetcode problem is to check whether the result can be uniquely generated from a list of lists of strings.

The following code is modified from the Python solution [here](https://leetcode.com/problems/sequence-reconstruction/discuss/303864/Python3-BFS-topological-sort) by user jinjiren. Note that the result is not unique.

First, generate the graphs using dictionary and count the indegree of each node.

```
values = {val for seq in seqs for val in seq}
graphs = {val: [] for val in values}
indegrees = {val: 0 for val in values}
for seq in seqs:
    for i in range(len(seq) - 1):
        src, tgt = seq[i], seq[i + 1]
        graphs[src].append(tgt)
        indegrees[tgt] += 1
```

Then, collect all nodes with 0 indegree, and put these nodes into a queue. We will keep adding nodes into `queue` later.

```
queue = collections.deque()
for val, degree in indegrees.items():
    if degree == 0:
        queue.append(val)
```

In the while loop, pop the first node of `queue` and append it to `result` list. Iterate over the connected nodes of the source node, minus 1 degree. If the degree of node becomes 0, then add the node to `queue`

```
result = []
while queue:
    src = queue.popleft()
    result.append(src)
    for tgt in graphs[src]:
        indegrees[tgt] -= 1
        if indegrees[tgt] == 0:
            queue.append(tgt)
```

Example 1

```
seqs = [
    ["Pikachu", "Charmander", "Bulbasaur"],
    ["Charmander", "Ditto"],
    ["Bulbasaur", "Arcanine", "Venusaur"],
    ["Ditto", "Bulbasaur", "Venusaur"],
]

>>> ["Pikachu", "Charmander", "Ditto", "Bulbasaur", "Arcanine", "Venusaur"]
```

Example 2

```
seqs = [
    ["A", "C", "D"],
    ["C", "B", "Y"],
    ["X", "Y"],
]

>>> ["A", "X", "C", "D", "B", "Y"]
```

Answer (score -1):

```
l=[
    ["Pikachu", "Charmander", "Bulbasaur"],
    ["Charmander", "Ditto"],
    ["Bulbasaur", "Arcanine", "Venusaur"],
    ["Ditto", "Bulbasaur", "Venusaur"],
]

import itertools

k=list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(l))

print(list(set(k)))
```

or

```
result=sum(l,[])

print(list(set(result)))
```